# How does a hedged portfolio account for other greeks?

Tags: options, hedging, greeks

- So a classic delta-hedged portfolio on a call option is:
  $$-C - \Phi(d) \cdot B + \frac{d}{dS}C \cdot S = 0$$
- How is risk of other Greeks hedged? Is it something like this?
  $$-C - \Phi(d') \cdot B + \text{max}\left(\frac{d}{dS}C, \frac{d^{2}}{dS^{2}}C, \frac{d}{d \sigma}C, \frac{d}{d r}C, \frac{d}{dt}C\right) \cdot S = 0$$